# Integrated Intel HD Graphics not detecting DVI diplay

Tags: intel-graphics

I just bought a desktop that has this chipset for graphics and I'm trying to hook up a second monitor. The first one is through VGA, the second one through the DVI port with a DVI to VGA converter. However, it's not detecintg that port / monitor.

I've verified I have the latest drivers etc

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You need more information. What is the motherboard model. Are these integrated graphics (well the MB model will tell us that :) )? What driver is the Video Card running and which version is it. Where did you get the driver from. Windows update I know messes this up sometimes with their suggested driver....specifically on the DVI port... Also what is the monitor model. I have an Intel integrated H67A-UD3H-B3 and if I instal the windows suggested Intel integrated driver update it ruins the DVI port and I have to plug D-SUB and uninstall the update and reapply the driver that came with the MB

Comment: I have experienced at least one graphics device that did not appear to support two analogue devices at once even though it had both VGA and DVI-A... this may be the problem in your case.